# how to get the id and number of elements in a column even if they are 0 in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

hope that you're doing well, I have two tables one is **module** and **element** the module contains elements so I have a foreign key of **moduleID** inside **element**, what I want to do is to show the ID of the module and the number of elements in that module, here what I did:

```
SELECT module.ID,count(element.ID) AS numElements FROM element JOIN module ON element.moduleID = module.ID WHERE moduleID = module.ID GROUP BY module.ID
```

But it shows only the modules that contain elements what about the modules that don't have any elements, I really hope if I can print them too and display in the count of their elemeents **0**.

**The columns of module table:**
ID(P) | moduleName | classID | upload_dir

**The columns of element table:**
ID(P) | elementName | moduleID(F) | teacherID(F) | icon | thumbnail | upload_dir

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT m.ID, count(e.ID) AS numElements
FROM module m LEFT JOIN
     element e
     ON e.moduleID = m.ID 
GROUP BY m.ID;
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of your `WHERE` clause was.  I suspect it was an attempt to get the missing rows.  If you want to filter this by element, add the condition in the `ON` clause.

Comment: it worked thank you so much for your fast replying